# Blowing bubbles on Shabbos

Tags: halacha, shabbat, minor-katan-child, melacha-creative-work, games-toys

Is there any halachik problem with blowing bubbles on Shabbos?  If so what melacha categories does it fall under?  Does the age of the blower matter?

Answer (score 15):

I am quoting you Rabbi Ribiat The 39 Melachos:

> Some Poskim advise that one should not
>   blow soap bubbles on Shabbbos because
>   this entails a semblance of
>   creating,which should be avoided.(One
>   should also not deliberately form
>   bubbles from bubble
>   gum.)Nevertheless,one need not
>   restrict young children from blowing
>   the bubbles on SHABBOS.

Comment: YS, good quote. Just remeber that that sefer is not a p'sak sefer for many reasons that it would be innappropriate to delineate here.

Comment: Is allusion any more appropriate than deliniation? Now, your objections are left to our imaginations ...

Comment: I am not objecting to this specific psak. I am referring to the reality that Rabbi Ribiat, who is a great Girls' High School halacha teacher does not have extensive shimush in psak halacha. He asserts certain psakim in his books and marginalizes many p'sakim that are really mainstream, many of them (surprise, surprise) kulos (leniencies). He will certainly choose a chumrah from the Chazon Ish over a kulah of Rav Moshe and a chumrah of Rav Moshe over a kulah of Rav Shlomo Zalman. It's a great sefer to learn the Melachos from, but leave the p'sak halacha to a real live Rav.

Comment: @Yahu: Although the footnotes in the back are great, and it seems he does bring the differing opinions there. With sources so you can look it up yourself.

Comment: Who are "some poskim"? What are the sources?

Comment: @SimchasTorah can you bring the sources from the back of the book/bottom of the page?

Comment: @Yahu Although I do find occasional halachic statements or reasoning that I disagree with (in those instances, the sefer is usually more strict then I think is justified), I find the rulings to be sound and well supported the great majority of the time. I don't think your statement that `he will certainly choose a chumrah from the Chazon Ish...` is quite accurate. Of course, you should CYLOR for halachic rulings, but, if you can review the footnotes and evaluate the cited sources yourself you should be able to get a good grasp of the halacha in the overwhelming majority of cases.

Comment: R. Ribiat is R. Belsky's nephew and the Rav of a shul, not accurate to say that he doesn't have experience in psak @yahu

Comment: @wfb Yesh shimush viYeish shimush. Gedolei Yisrael, Rebbe'im of mine, particularly talmidim of Reb Moshe ZT"L have warned me against using his seforim for p'sak halakha. He may be more adept at tailoring his psakim to the specific contexts in the Rav-congregant setting, but the conclusions in his seforim are excellent examples of the exclamation of chazal "Is there such a thing as Hora'a liChumra?"

Comment: @Yahu R. Moshe advised against publishing kulos in English, so he may be following R. Moshe more than your realize

Answer (score 7):

The [Rivevos Ephraim Chelek 8:564:1](http://www.hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=1082&pgnum=451) was asked if one can blow bubbles from chewing gum(bazuka). He writes that making bubbles from soap was discussed in Shmiras Shabbas Kehilchasa perek 17:30 and says that one shouldn't make them. However, he writes that one shouldn't refrain a child from doing so,and the reason written in the name of Rav Shlomo Zalamn Aurbach is that the bubble inst permanent(no kiyum).

The Rivevos EPhraim uses this logic by gum and writes that making a bubble from gum lasts for a moment and then rips and has no permanence(kiyum). Therefore he writes that it should be permitted. However,he adds that bnei Torah and their children should be machmir. He ends off by saying that in genreal chewing gum isn't a nice thing for a bnei Torah and should be avoided even during the week.

Rav Abadi in his [Ohr Yitzchak 1:192](http://hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=1525&st=&pgnum=218&hilite=) writes:

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Shmirat Shabbat Kehilchatah 16:30:

> Although adults should not blow soap bubbles, one need not stop children from doing so.

He adds in a footnote that he heard the leniency (of allowing children to blow bubbles) from Shlomo Zalman Auerbach ZTL. The reason was due to the impermanence of the bubbles.