# Rinse with baking soda and water on Shabbos?

Tags: shabbat, medicine, melacha-creative-work, face, personal-hygiene

Are you allowed to mix a pinch of baking soda with water and rinse your mouth with it instead of using mouthwash?

Also there are two way to mix it: place some baking soda on your finger/hand and drop it in your mouth, followed by as sip of some water; the other way is to mix it in a cup with a spoon. Is there a halachic difference in regards how this "mixture" is created?

The possible *melachos/gezeiros* involved are: making medicine, kneading, changing the form of an object, and possibly adding the final touches.

Answer (score 1):

R Yisroel Pinchos Bodner ([Halachos of refuah on Shabbos](https://www.feldheim.com/halachos-of-refuah-on-shabbos), p. 32) writes

> **One may rinse out his mouth on Shabbos with non-medicated mouthwash to
> freshen hhis breath and teeth**. He may also use breath-freshening drops
> or strips, **because removing an odor is not an act of healing**.

Note this would not be permitted for a medical use (see e.g., [here](http://www.sephardichalacha.org/2015/07/) under July 13, 2015 and [here](https://www.halachafortoday.com/shabbos-pikuach) under February 3, 2019).

Making soda itself on Shabbat is permitted, see [here](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/1390/making-seltzer-soda-water-on-shabbat-or-yom-tov) or [here](https://outorah.org/p/81434/).

Of course, [consult your rabbi](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/9146)
before implementing anything [you learn here](https://judaism.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1734).