# Halachik issues with SodaStream and similar sodamakers on Shabbos (e.g. molid, hashmaas kol)

Tags: halacha, shabbat, appliances, issur-hashmaat-kol

It is disputed whether soda/seltzer makers are a problem on *Shabbos* (see [Making seltzer/soda water on Shabbat or Yom Tov](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/1390/making-seltzer-soda-water-on-shabbat-or-yom-tov/51281#51281) ) with e.g. the *Shemiras Shabbos K'hilchasa* ruling leniently (as cited in Rabbi Dovid Ribiat's "The 39 *Melochos*").

The focus in these works seems to be primarily *m'leches makeh b'patish* (completing) (and/or uvda d'chol [weekday activities]).  Is there an explicit discussion in the poskim, with regard to soda-makers, of the issue of molid (creating something new; a la, e.g., the Rabbinic ban on infusing clothing with incense smoke)?

Also, the [instructions](http://compliant.sodastream.com/faq) (at least on the SodaStream sodamaker) make explicit use of the sounds created by the device to determine when the seltzer is ready (e.g. "press the carbonating button several times until you hear the LOUD BUZZ that indicates carbonation"). Do *poskim* address whether this is a problem of the Rabbinic ban on *hashmaas kol* (making a noise)?

Comment: If you like an answer consider making it correct. If not, consider clarifying what additional information you want.

Answer (score 3):

Regarding the issue of hashmaas kol, see Darkei Moshe (Orach Chaim 252, 7) who quotes a number of Rishonim who understood that hashmaas kol is prohibited only if the sound will cause people to suspect you did something prohibited on Shabbat, like if they hear the flour grinder churning they will suspect you are operating it on Shabbat (even though you set it up before Shabbat). But if the sound will not cause suspicion (like by a clock which everyone knows is set up before Shabbat) there is no prohibition. Based on this logic poskim have permitted the use of refrigerators, air conditioners etc. even though they may make a lot of noise, since no one will come to suspect that one has operated them on Shabbat.
Accordingly, if it is permitted to use the SodaStream on Shabbat, then the noise is not problematic as it will not incur suspicion that one is doing something prohibited. 
Additionaly, the noise usually discussed by hashmaas kol is noise that is loud enough to be heard by people outside (and thus raise the suspicion). I am not sure that a SodaStream is indeed that loud.

Comment: Shouldn't that mean that, assuming electricity is not a problem/involved, using a doorbell/door-knocker/*grogger*/kazoo should also be allowed?