# Blowing Bubbles on Yom Tov

Tags: halacha, melacha-creative-work, yom-tov, games-toys

Is anything wrong with blowing bubbles on Yom Tov? Would it be different than [blowing bubbles on Shabbos](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/741/blowing-bubbles-on-shabbos)?

Comment: Hey, welcome to Mi Yodeya! Nice question. Please consider [registering](//judaism.stackexchange.com/users/signup-unregistered) your account, to [enable](//meta.stackexchange.com/questions/44557/why-should-i-register-my-account) more site features, including voting. I suggest that you [edit your profile](//judaism.stackexchange.com/users/edit/current) and give yourself a name!

Comment: why do you think yom tov should be different than shabbas? Ochel nefesh is the one big difference,anything not connected to food should be similiar to shabbas

Comment: Isn't Nolad also different on yom tov?

Comment: user14481 Tip for you: if you want to be sure that someone will see your response to them in the comments, include their name in your comment, prefaced by the `@` symbol. I'm not sure that @sam saw your response. (Also, if Nolad is an important part of your question, I recommend that you [edit] that in. It will improve both your question, as well as answers you'll get from it)

Comment: Sorry, that's not how it works. [You cannot ping anyone by typing something into a post (or edit summary).](https://judaism.meta.stackexchange.com/a/2068/5323)