# Book on the laws of Shabbos

Tags: shabbat, product-recommendation, jewish-books, contemporary-halacha

Which English book on the laws of Shabbos would you recommend?

One that is *Halacha Lemaase* with footnotes that show where the Halacha stems from and the differentiating opinions.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There are multiple options depending on how much of a reference book you are searching for vs. something which is readable cover-to-cover to rehearse.

- [The 39 melochos](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B00382JJD6) is an amazing reference work but it is very heavy (ca. 2000 pages) and detailed. Serves best to check out or learn in depth a specific *melacha* with Hebrew footnotes to enable further study
- [Shemirath Shabbath KeHilchata](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/1583304940) remains a classic, can be read cover to cover (although a bit heavy) and doesn't address more recent technology innovations
- [R Simcha Bunim Cohen's set](https://www.artscroll.com/Books/9781422615072.html) feels more readable since each volume only covers specific topics (e.g., the home, the kitchen, *muktze*, *amira l'akum*) and is focused on *halacha l'maase* but (Hebrew) footnotes bring a variety of opinions
- R Daniel Braude's [Learn Shabbos in Just 3 Minutes A Day](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/1988022304) is a very recent book which is structured along the 39 *melachot*, it brings the *halacha* for each with background, lots of practical day-to-day examples and sources (mostly SA, MB, SSK and *piskei aharonim* focused on R SZ Auerbach, R Eliashiv). Its title stems from the fact it is broken down in 500 or so sections which can be learned in a few minutes. It is both highly readable and quite deep

Comment: I am traveling at present but happy to provide a few "inside pictures" towards the end of the week if useful

Comment: Ty. Y'all are awesome. @mbloch

Answer (score 5):

Piskei Shabbas by Rabbi Eliezer Padwar is also very helpful sefer. It is 4 volumes (Yom tov as one vol) . It is in English and has footnotes. Many of the psakim are from Rav Moshe Feinstein ,and the Debercheiner Rav. Many people also use Rav Simcha Bunim Cohen's seforim ,which has good notes (Many times contain more lenient opinions). There is also Rav Shimon Eiders sefer on shabbas as well.

[image]

Sample page:

[image]

Rav Cohen's books:

[image]

Rabbi Eider:
[image]

Comment: Do you know where I can buy the set? @sam

Comment: It's out of print for a long time,but check here https://www.amazon.com/s?k=Ephraim+Eliezer+Padawer&i=stripbooks&ref=mw_dp_a_s

Comment: +1 for Piskei Hilchos Shabbos. I loved that when I was younger, and as I grew, I enjoyed the Hebrew section in the back.

Comment: It's great,but I think it is very strict for many things .

Answer (score 4):

[*The 39 Melochos*](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B00382JJD6) by Rabbi Dovid Ribiat. I haven't used it that often myself, but in my experience of observing others this seems to be one of the most, if not the most, highly regarded English books about the laws of Shabbos. The few times that I *have* used it it seemed to do a good job of laying out the concepts and providing the relevant sources.

Comment: However you really need the Hebrew footnotes in the back.  In the front he sometimes oversimplifies the concepts.  (For halacha lemaaseh the front is probably fine.)

Comment: See also comments to https://judaism.stackexchange.com/a/742/170

Comment: Also most of the leneinces are in the Hebrew footnotes